Мне нужно чтобы при вводе числа в поле ввода на странице сайта, это число записывалось в текстовый документ
Какие существуют функции в html для чтения и редактирования текстовых файлов (.txt)?

Никаких, html это не язык программирования

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

HTML (HyperText Markup Language) — это не язык программирования, а язык разметки (только отображения информации на веб-странице)
HTML не выполняет логику (как например сохранить в файл) и не может напрямую взаимодействовать с данными
для этого есть различные языки программирования (c#, js, ruby, java ...)
если вам нужно выполнять сложные задачи, такие как чтение/запись данных в файлы, вам понадобится использование серверных технологий или JavaScript на стороне клиента.
приведу пример JavaScript - создаёт текстовый файл на стороне клиента и предлагает его пользователю для скачивания,  но не сохраняет на сервере к примеру


document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // введенное число
  const number = document.getElementById('numberInput').value;

  // полезно почитать https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Blob
  const blob = new Blob([number], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });

  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = 'number.txt';

  link.click();

  // чистить память не забываем
  URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
});
<form id="myForm">
  <label for="numberInput">Введите число:</label>
  <input type="number" id="numberInput" name="number" required>
  <button type="submit">Записать в файл</button>
</form>



